# How do I remove http artifacts from a multipart form-data request?

Tags: java, file-upload, jersey, multipartform-data

I have this method signature in a jersery servlet. The servlet is being reached and the form data is present in the uploadedInputStream object, but the stream does not have the http artifacts removed from it. See below.

```
@POST
@Produces("text/plain")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public String uploadFileIE(
    @FormDataParam("qqfile") InputStream uploadedInputStream ){

}
```

When saved to a file, the input stream has these artifacts surrounding the byte data:

```
-----------------------------7dc1f42e3005a8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="qqfile";filename="[filename]"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

[bytes from data stream]
-----------------------------7dc1f42e3005a8--
```

Shouldn't these artifacts be removed already at this point? Is there any easy way to remove them without re-inventing the wheel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Jersey you need to 'consume' the extra header information with a FormDataContentDisposition object. Messy but necessary:

```
@POST
@Produces("text/plain")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public String uploadFileIE(
    @FormDataParam("qqfile") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
    @FormDataParam("qqfile") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail){

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was kicking my ass all day.

Comment: I think this is not so simple. It is not working on me :(