# Sharepoint file upload renders a file partially corrupted when uploaded using a python script

Tags: javascript, python, firefox, sharepoint

Using the python requests module I perform a multipart post to sharepoint. The file, in this case a microsoft pptx file, is uploaded successfully. There are issues with the file when I try and open the uploaded file however.

[image: error warning]

[image: repair warning]

Powerpoint requests that the file be repaired and when I press the repair the file does seem to open correctly (I haven't noticed anything missing).

I took a look at the request headers and notice that the content-length differs when the post happens through the firefox browser as opposed to the post through my script.

Here are the headers that firefox submits:
[image: firefox request headers]

Here are the headers that my script submits:
[image: script request headers]

The file size on disk = 17,938,612

Content length with my script = 17,938,874

Content length with firefox = 17,939,026

I guess I don't know why the content length differs and I suspect if this is happening because of that difference.

When I submit the post request using my script, I do not encode the data and prepare the post request as such:

```
postheader.update({'Accept':'application/json; odata=verbose','Content-Type':'application/json; odata=verbose', 'X-RequestDigest':formdigestvalue, 'binaryStringRequestBody':'true'})

filetoupload = {'file':(filename, open(filename, 'rb'), 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation')}
posturl = projectConfig.sharepointurl + "/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('Shared Documents/release_doc/"+project+"')/files/add(url='"+filename+"', overwrite='true')"
response = requests.post(posturl, headers=postheader, files=filetoupload, cookies=postcookies)
```

UPDATE:

I took a look at the file that I uploaded using my script and it has the following headers still attached in the content:

```
--6ab0a06f1ddc432186194dd48355eac1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ZZZ Technology Guide.pptx"; filename="ZZZ Technology Guide.pptx"
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
Expires: 0

<file content>
--6ab0a06f1ddc432186194dd48355eac1--
```

However the file that was uploaded through firefox did not have these headers. I'm thinking I need to call a sharepoint function (if there is a REST API that does that) to process the file after it is uploaded or if there's a method in the `python requests` that can dispose off these headers as mentioned in this post: [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947846/how-do-i-remove-http-artifacts-from-a-multipart-form-data-request)