# Uploading file on sharepoint with python causes uploaded file to retain headers in the content

Tags: python, sharepoint, http-headers

When I submit the post request using my script, I do not encode the data and prepare the post request as such:

```
postheader.update({'Accept':'application/json; odata=verbose','Content-Type':'application/json; odata=verbose', 'X-RequestDigest':formdigestvalue, 'binaryStringRequestBody':'true'})

filetoupload = {'file':(filename, open(filename, 'rb'), 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation')}
posturl = projectConfig.sharepointurl + "/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('Shared Documents/release_doc/"+project+"')/files/add(url='"+filename+"', overwrite='true')"
response = requests.post(posturl, headers=postheader, files=filetoupload, cookies=postcookies)
```

I took a look at the file that I uploaded using my script and it has the following headers still attached in the content:

```
--6ab0a06f1ddc432186194dd48355eac1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ZZZ Technology Guide.pptx"; filename="ZZZ Technology Guide.pptx"
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation

<file content>
--6ab0a06f1ddc432186194dd48355eac1--
```

However the file that was uploaded through firefox did not have these headers. I'm thinking I need to call a sharepoint function (if there is a REST API that does that) to process the file after it is uploaded or if there's a method in the python requests that can dispose off these headers as mentioned in this post: [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947846/how-do-i-remove-http-artifacts-from-a-multipart-form-data-request)

Comment: Is it the "Content-Disposition" header you don't want to see ?

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this?

Comment: No I never managed to find a solution so I did a workaround. Instead I mapped the sharepoint as a directory and just copied files to the mapped drive instead. It's not the best way of doing it nor is it failsafe but for now it's doing the job and when I get a server reboot I get issues with mapping the drive which I'm looking into fixing. If you find a solution let me know. I'm willing to share my code!

Answer (score 1):

Do NOT use multipart/form-data
i.e.
in the curl world, use "--data-binary "@testFile.xls" instead of -F upload="@testFile.xls"

Answer (score 0):

If it is working fine with Firefox, it will normally work too with python requests module.

Did you double-check the [requests docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) relative to "post-a-multipart-encoded-file" ?

In Firefox:firebug under the network tab you may right-click on the request and then select "Copy as cURL" for double-checking purpose...

Comment: This should be a comment